# json api out is changed when using nginx to serve the app

Tags: python, json, flask, ember-data

I'm using flask-restful package to create the api for my ember webapp, from what I read, ember is very particular about the json formating.

this is my flask code:

```
def toJson(data):
    return json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True, indent=4, default=json_util.default)


@app.route('/PS/api_v1_0/', methods=['GET'])
def Listing():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        lim = int(request.args.get('limit', 10))
        off = int(request.args.get('offset', 0))
        results = db['Listing'].find().skip(off).limit(lim)
        json_results = []
        for result in results:
            json_results.append(result)
        return toJson(json_results)
```

but the return i get is like this:

```
[ { "exterior_color": "White", "interior_color": "Black", "make": "BMW", "mmr_price": null, "model": "640I", "odometer": 11530, "trim": "CPE 640I", "year": "2016" } ]
```

(edit: this does not work with ember js, I need a way to return json that can work with ember js, below is an example of what I think the will work with ember, but I'm not sure)

where I'm expecting a result more like this:

```
[
{
    "exterior_color": "White",
    "interior_color": "Black",
    "make": "BMW",
    "mmr_price": null,
    "model": "640I",
    "odometer": 11530,
    "trim": "CPE 640I",
    "year": "2016"
}
]
```

I just can't seem to figure how to get it like that. any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Isn't that the exact same thing?

Comment: @spectras it is but if you read the very first part, ember js seems to have strict way it wants the json return to be formatted, so it won't work with the first output.

Comment: It is not about the spacing, it's about the actual content… give me a second.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume you are using ember-data. If so, then the format is incorrect, it should be:

```
{
    cars: [
    {
        "exteriorColor": "White",
        "interiorColor": "Black",
        "make": "BMW",
        "mmrPrice": null,
        "model": "640I",
        "odometer": 11530,
        "trim": "CPE 640I",
        "year": "2016"
    }
    ]
}
```

You will find the relevant documentation here: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html

I guess you could change your code this way, but you still need to camel case the keys.

```
return toJson({
    'cars': json_results,
})
```

That is assuming your ember model is named `Car`.

Another alternative is to keep you JSON the same, and customize the way `ember-data` parses it by defining your own normalization hooks in a custom  [JSONSerializer](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONSerializer.html).